# Java Generic: Can a Generic extends another Generic class?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Here, here is my question, I have three abstracts class which all are generic, and i want something like this:

```
public abstract class AbstracOne< T extends AbstractTwo< K extends AbstractThree<K> >>>
```

This is not working and I get the following error (on the second extends):

*Syntax error on token "extends", , expected.*

However, if I use the following code, it is working:

```
public abstract class AbstracOne< T extends AbstractTwo< ? extends AbstractThree<?> >>>
```

So, what is the difference between using K and ?

Thank you very much

Comment: The use of `K` attempts to introduce a new type parameter. You can't do that in a type argument use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Type parameter vs Type argument

You can read this excellent [FAQ by Angelica Langer](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html) for clearing this distinction.

Generic class has type parameters which are substituted by type argument when you use the generic class.

Type parameters can have constraints. Type arguments can be fully qualified types or previously defined type parameters.

So, you can use `K` if it is defined already. You can also add constraints while defining it.

```
public abstract class AbstractOne<K extends AbstractThree<K>, T extends AbstractTwo<K>>
```

Good luck.

Comment: Glad to know it helped

Comment: can you elaborate on the K extends AbstractThree<K>, are both the K's the same class? If so how can it extend itself?

Comment: It is a recursive constraint. You could substitute a class for K which is defined like `class MyFoo extends AbstractThree<MyFoo>`